# Pagination not working properly Android. It is showing all item at a time

Tags: android, performance

I have recyclerview with 30 items in it. When i try to scroll pagination is not working. It is showing all items instead of refreshing. Below is my code.

```
public class InstitutesWithSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
PaginationAdapter adapter;
private static final int PAGE_START = 1;
private boolean isLoading, isLastPage = false;
private int TOTAL_PAGES = 2;
int itemCount = 0;
private int currentPage = PAGE_START;
ApiInterface apiInterface;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter = new PaginationAdapter(this);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;

            //mocking network delay for api
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadNextPage();
                }
            },2000);
        }

        @Override
        public int getTotalPageCount() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });

    //init service and load data
    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
     loadFirstPage();
}
private void loadNextPage() {
    Call<InstituteResponseModel> call = apiInterface.masterInstitutes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<InstituteResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InstituteResponseModel> call, Response<InstituteResponseModel> response) {
            adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            isLoading = false;
            ArrayList<InstituteModel> results = fetchResults(response);
            adapter.addAll(results);
            if (currentPage != PAGE_START) adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
            adapter.addAll(results);

            if (currentPage < TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;
            isLoading = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InstituteResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

private void loadFirstPage() {
    Log.e(TAG,"loadFirstPage");

    Call<InstituteResponseModel> call = apiInterface.masterInstitutes();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<InstituteResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InstituteResponseModel> call, Response<InstituteResponseModel> response) {
            ArrayList<InstituteModel> results = fetchResults(response);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.addAll(results);

            if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) adapter.addLoadingFooter();
            else isLastPage = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InstituteResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<InstituteModel> fetchResults(Response<InstituteResponseModel> response) {
    InstituteResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
    return  responseModel.getData();
}
```

}

I don't know what is the mistake from my side. I'm new to this pagination concept. I'm getting example code which uses forloop to show data. I'm using API to show data in Recyclerview.

public class PaginationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
boolean isLoadingAdded = false;

private ArrayList<InstituteModel> modelArrayList;
Context context;

public PaginationAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public ArrayList<InstituteModel> getInstitutes() {
    return modelArrayList;
}

public void setInstitutes(ArrayList<InstituteModel> modelArrayList) {
    this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType){
        case ITEM:
            viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoadingVH(v2);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater){
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.institute_row_layout, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new InstituteHolder(v1);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int parent) {
    InstituteModel model = modelArrayList.get(parent);
    switch (getItemViewType(parent)){
        case ITEM:
            final InstituteHolder instituteHolder = (InstituteHolder) holder;
            instituteHolder.instName.setText(model.getInstituteName());
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(model.getImageURL())
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            instituteHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            instituteHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(instituteHolder.instImg);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelArrayList == null ? 0 : modelArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == modelArrayList.size()-1 && isLoadingAdded) ? LOADING : ITEM;
}

public void add(InstituteModel m){
    modelArrayList.add(m);
    notifyItemInserted(modelArrayList.size()-1);
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<InstituteModel> modelsList){
    for (InstituteModel model : modelsList){
        add(model);
    }
}

public void remove(InstituteModel model){
    int position = modelArrayList.indexOf(model);
    if (position > -1){
        modelArrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void clear(){
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    while (getItemCount()>0){
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return  getItemCount() == 0;
}

public void addLoadingFooter(){
    isLoadingAdded = true;
    add(new InstituteModel());
}


public void removeLoadingFooter(){
    isLoadingAdded = false;
    int position = modelArrayList.size() -1;
    InstituteModel result = getItem(position);
    if (result != null){
        modelArrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public InstituteModel getItem(int position){return  modelArrayList.get(position);}

protected class InstituteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView instName;
    ImageView instImg;
    TextView cityName, areaName;
    RelativeLayout cardView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public InstituteHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        instImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_image);
        instName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_name);
        areaName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_area);
        cityName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_city);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProgress);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}

protected class LoadingVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LoadingVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In the above InstituteActivity if i change TOTAL_PAGES=3 number my list is generating 3 times with same data. I don't want to show same data for three times. I i place TOTAL_PAGES=1 it shows my data 1 time without pagination effect i.e bottom refreshing effect for every 10 items

Comment: instead of those custom scroll listeners and lots of boilerplate code use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support library

Comment: @pskink I didn't understand

Comment: you are not fetching data based on page index. Also, you are adding data 2 times on loadNextPage method. Check if the data returned on API call is same or different

Comment: `"The Paging Library helps you load and display small chunks of data at a time. Loading partial data on demand reduces usage of network bandwidth and system resources."` - just follow the link i posted above